# Do not map Realm object into Realm table

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Basically my problem is that I want to define a realm object (`RealmSwift.Object` subclass) and I do not want it to appear in the Realm database, instruct Realm to skip this one.

**For example:**

I want to implement a synchronisation logic in a private pod with dynamic list of objects that are all subclassed from an object, called `SyncableObject`.

I have two classes that I register into my sync module (`ConcreteClassA` and `ConcreteClassB`) like `SyncModule.register([ConcreteClassA.self, ConcreteClassB.self])`.

Now Realm detects that I have 3 `RealmSwift.Object` subclasses and creates 3 different tables.

I want a solution to instruct Realm, not to create the table for the `SyncableObject` (intermediate object) class, like overriding a class function or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to override `+[RLMObject shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema]`. From [Realm's source](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v0.98.6/Realm/RLMObjectBase.h#L37-L38):

```
// Returns whether the class is included in the default set of classes persisted in a Realm.
+ (BOOL)shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema;
```

Comment: Thank you! It is definitely what I was looking for. I was searching for this because I knew I saw it somewhere, but could not actually locate it when I needed.

Answer (score 1):

By upgrading the previous solutions, I figured that this will do the trick to not include the base object and do include the subclasses:

```
/**
 Do not include SyncableObject into schema, only the subclasses
 */
public override class func shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema() -> Bool {
    return SyncableObject.className() != self.className()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer in `Swift`:

```
override class func shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema() -> Bool {
   return false
}
```